# Change doorkeeper base models for application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, mongoid, doorkeeper

I'm just wondering if there is any way to change the application model class for doorkeeper to authorize clients. I've basically an identical model for other purposes and want to reuse this also for authenticating the client.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing same problem.
Even if it is not a clean solution, you could add a one-to-one relationship between your custom application model and the oauth application model introduced by doorkeeper.

Did you find any other solution?

Comment: I switched to use the doorkeeper application model directly with the other models which had a relation to my original application model and I've overwritten the doorkeeper application model to extend it with the fields I needed for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Doorkeeper 5.3, you can change doorkeeper base models for application, access_token and access_grant. Check it out here: https://doorkeeper.gitbook.io/guides/configuration/models